# How to change `branch-2`'s base branch from `branch-1` (which is already merged to `development`) to `development`

Tags: git, github

Say, there are two branches.

1. `branch-1` and it's base branch is `development`
2. `branch-2` and it's base branch is `branch-1`

Now `branch-1` is merged to `development`.

Question is: **"Is it possible to change `branch-2`'s base branch from `branch-1` to `development`, if yes how?"**

Comment: What happens when you do `git rebase development` while on `branch-2`?

Comment: When you say "base branch" you mean that a branch is set _on top_ of its base branch, right?

Comment: If the answer to my question is "yes", then what @RichS is saying is what you have to do.

Comment: I mean, `base branch: from which a new branch had been created`

Comment: yes, I'm just going to do that, but bit afraid of it... a lots of changes there (so risky).

Comment: what I usually do is create a "merge candidate" branch (`git checkout -b branch-2-mc`), which is an identical copy of the branch I want to toy with. That way if I screw up, I can always just delete it and try again. And if things do go well, I just delete the merge candidate branch after merging.

Comment: This is git... if you don't like what it looks like, you can always go back to where you were before rebasing with a `git reset --hard` so go ahead.

Comment: ... or that also.

Comment: Actually, you can do the operation without using a branch. `git checkout --detach && git rebase development`. If you like the results: `git branch -f branch-2 && git checkout branch-2`.

Comment: @eftshift0's most recent comment is my favorite way. Done in 1-2 lines. It should work as long as all the changes you made in `branch-2` have been committed and you run those commands while still on that branch.

Comment: what I did: created branch from `branch-2` and named `branch-2-safe`. And then rebased `development` onto `branch-2-safe` and then pushed

Comment: Problem solved, right?

Comment: yup :) thanks a lot guys :)